# Ion-select doesn't scroll in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

[image]

This select contains the list of all countries in register form. The point is that the ion-content in the form page is scrollable but select it self is not scrolling. 
Here is the code:

```
 <ion-item>
       <ion-select interface="action-sheet" class="select" placeholder="Country">
          <ion-option ngDefaultControl [value]='country.name' *ngFor="let country of countries">{{country.name}}
          </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
       </ion-item>
```

Why select scroll is not working?

Comment: Which ionic 3 version are you using right now?

Comment: ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
 "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.2",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.20",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.9.1",

Comment: But cli is 4.10.1

Comment: @AniruddhThakor can you please recommend the best version of ionic 3 where select scrolling works for you?

Comment: Even, in Ionic4 also its not scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, you can track at https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17311#issuecomment-460829890

Ionic have provided a workaround by setting following css in global.scss

```
.action-sheet-group {
    overflow: auto !important;
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in ionic 4 using interface=popover.  The solution was to make a global css class:

```
.my-select-scrollable .popover-viewport {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

then add this attribute to the ion-select

```
[interfaceOptions]="{cssClass: 'm-select-scrollable'}"
```

You could also avoid the attribute with this in the global css file:

```
ion-select {
  overflow: scroll !important;
}
```